# How to display data in Shopify Store from external API using app proxy

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

My goal is to display data retrieved from a 3rd party (external) API that requires authentication in my Liquid Shopify theme.

I'm looking to access product options data from the Hulk Product Options API, which requires authentication, as documented here: https://productoption.hulkapps.com/api-docs/index.html

My goal would be to send a get request and retrieve data from the Hulk Product Options endpoint.

I've read that an App Proxy is what I need to set up, however I am new to the Shopify app world and am totally lost at how to set this up.

What I've done:

1. Followed [the steps here](https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create) to create an app and install it on a development store that I created through my partners dashboard.
2. Went to the partners dashboard, clicked "Apps" and found the app proxy section.

Questions:

1. What do I put in those fields? I can't find examples for filling out that section with info from an external API.
2. What code in which file do I need to add to the node app that was generated using `shopify node create`. Or is this app just necessary to be able to fill out the app proxy info?
3. What url can I send a GET request to using AJAX / JS in my liquid theme code?

I'm a theme developer new to app development and have never created an app, so if you can provide basic and specific instructions (code would be wonderful!) for someone who knows front-end and is competent but is lost in the app world it's much appreciated. I've asked other theme developers who also have also tried and not been able to figure this out, so there seems to be a gap in the tutorials and resources provided.

Thanks in advance!